# How to auto-remove orphaned rows in TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a one-to-many relation in TypeORM and I would like to delete rows from the many side of the relationship rather than unlinking them by setting their foreign key to null (the default behavior), leaving them orphaned.  How can this be done? I saw [a PR](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/1665) for this feature but it was rejected. Is there a workaround or some other way to do this? Here's a simplified version of my code to give some context.

```js
@Entity()
@TableInheritance({ column: { name: 'type', type: 'text' } })
export default class Geolocation {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @IsGeoJSONPoint
  @Column('geography')
  point!: Point;
}


@ChildEntity('offer')
export default class OfferGeolocation extends Geolocation {
  @ManyToOne(type => Offer, offer => offer.geolocations, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  offer!: Offer;
}


@ChildEntity('business')
export default class BusinessGeolocation extends Geolocation {
  @ManyToOne(type => Business, business => business.geolocations, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  business!: Business;
}


@Entity()
export default class Business {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  // I would like to remove orphaned business geolocations
  @OneToMany(type => BusinessGeolocation, businessGeolocation => businessGeolocation.business, { cascade: true })
  geolocations!: BusinessGeolocation[];
}


@Entity()
export default class Offer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  // I would like to remove orphaned offer geolocations as well
  @OneToMany(type => OfferGeolocation, offerGeolocation => offerGeolocation.offer, { cascade: true })
  geolocations!: OfferGeolocation[];
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thinking i might just 'delete where col = null'?

Comment: @dale Nope, not yet :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was another [PR](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/7105) which was merged on Jan 12th 2021, which fixes this.

This feature is available since TypeORM version [0.2.30](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0230-2021-01-12):

> ### 0.2.30 (2021-01-12)
>
> #### Features
>
> - relations: Orphaned row action (#7105) (efc2837)

You should be able to achieve what you want by:

```
@ChildEntity('business')
export default class BusinessGeolocation extends Geolocation {
  @ManyToOne(
    type => Business, business => business.geolocations, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      orphanedRowAction: "delete" // NEW
    })
  business!: Business;
}
```

Comment: Hi, in this example, does it mean that if you remove a row in 'business' table (represented here by the entity BusinessGeolocation), THEN a row in the related entity of kind "Business" will be removed, ONLY WHEN this row in related entity of kind "Business" does not have any other row from 'business' table pointing to it?
So basically for now my undestanding is that it would work if i do something like:
await BusinessGeolocation.remove(varOfTypeBusinessGeolocation);
I have the same setup, minus the @childEntity() overhead, and it doesnt work for me, the related business entity remains...